# Is there any alternative to Apple ResearchKit for Android?

Tags: android, ios, researchkit

Is there any alternative to Apple ResearchKit for Android? or Is there any medical related API and Library for Android smartphones?

Thanks,

Comment: Look for Google StudyKit. Not sure if it is exactly what ResearchKit is.

Comment: @PrateekChaubey Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android version of ResearchKit is being currently built. It's called ResearchStack and I believe the beta version will be released in January.

Check  http://researchstack.org/ for more information

Comment: It's live now and code is on Github: https://github.com/ResearchStack/ResearchStack

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit is the Android equivalent of the Apple ResearchKit.  You can find out more here: https://developers.google.com/fit/?hl=en